# Magento 2.4.2: Do I need to override system.xml in my custom module to add a new tab, section, group and field in the admin backend?

Tags: system.xml, magento2.4.2, overriding

I need to set and get config data in Magento backend. I know that it is system.xml under module-backend that I need to add to. I am little confused as to how to override this file in my custom module. Could you please advise how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this create a system.xml like yours
you should section and group like your old module (in the custom module).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="payment">
        <group id="checkmo">
            <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label>Custom New Order Status</label> <!-- Custom label -->
            </field>  
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

also, you need to create a sequence

```
 <module name="Vendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_OfflinePayments"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: Your solution is not very clear. Could you please elaborate it? thanks

Comment: @CodeForGood check it again

Comment: Thanks, can you tell what would be the path to the field order_status?

Comment: Why is sequence necessary?

Comment: Please check my related post @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341545/magento-2-4-2-unable-to-set-and-get-custom-config-data-although-the-field-is-vi